# Odoo 16 - Uncaught Promise > Invalid props for component 'ProjectTaskFormController': unknown key 'model'

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-16, odoo-enterprise

I am getting this error when trying to open a Task from the Map view of Tasks (in a Project or otherwise). See attached screenshot.

I have extended the `project.task` model and some of its views in my own code so I am willing to accept that it might be my error, but I don't know how to start debugging this issue.

```
UncaughtPromiseError > OwlError
Uncaught Promise > Invalid props for component 'ProjectTaskFormController': unknown key 'model'
OwlError: Invalid props for component 'ProjectTaskFormController': unknown key 'model'
    at Object.validateProps (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:19239:19) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:3069)
    at View.slot1 (eval at compile (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:21606:16), <anonymous>:13:13) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:5436)
    at callSlot (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:19053:37) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:2883)
    at WithSearch.template (eval at compile (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:21606:16), <anonymous>:8:12) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:5436)
    at Fiber._render (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:17791:38) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:1621)
    at Fiber.render (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:17783:18) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:1613)
    at ComponentNode.initiateRender (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_common.js:18505:23) (/web/static/lib/owl/owl.js:2335)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled the latest commit of Odoo Enterprise (1ec67c2e) and the problem was resolved.